# Invert names of IDs in a form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the following form:

```
<form id="currency" name="form" onsubmit="return redirect(this)">

    <div style="clear:both;text-align: center;">
        <select id="firstcurrency" class="selex" name="firstcurrency" style="float: left;">
            <option value="usd">USD</option>
            <option value="btc">BTC</option>
        </select>

        <span style="margin: 0 auto;">=</span>

        <select id="secondcurrency" class="selex" name="secondcurrency" style="float: right;">
            <option value="btc">RRR</option>
            <option value="xvg">XVG</option>
            <option value="xrp">XRP</option>
            <option value="ntx">NTX</option>
        </select>
        <p style="clear: both;"></p>


    <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Redirect Me" ></p>
    <a href="convertitore-home"><img src="/images/invert.png">Invert select</a>
</form>
```

When I  click on `a` tag (outside the form), I want it to do two things:
1) invert the values of  `IDs` and `names` in the 2 `select` in the form above 2) change `float` values from left to right in the first `select` and from right to left in the second `select`.

After the click on `a` tag, the form should become:

```
<form id="currency" name="form" onsubmit="return redirect(this)">

    <div style="clear:both;text-align: center;">
        <select id="secondcurrency" class="selex1" name="secondcurrency" style="float: right;">
            <option value="usd">USD</option>
            <option value="btc">BTC</option>
        </select>

        <span style="margin: 0 auto;">=</span>

        <select id="firstcurrency" class="selex2" name="firstcurrency" style="float: left;">
            <option value="btc">RRR</option>
            <option value="xvg">XVG</option>
            <option value="xrp">XRP</option>
            <option value="ntx">NTX</option>
        </select>
        <p style="clear: both;"></p>


    <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Redirect Me" ></p>
    <a href="convertitore-home"><img src="/images/invert.png">Invert select</a>
</form>
```

It should do it again each time I press `a` tag.

What Javascript code would you use to do that?

Comment: Stackoverflow is used for answering bugs / specific questions; not for solving homework problems. Solutions for this have been documented before, I am sure you can learn a way to handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add separate css for the currencies then use this :

```js
$('#invert').click(function(){
    var firstCurr = $('#firstcurrency'),
        secondCurr = $('#secondcurrency'),
        tmpID = secondCurr.attr('id');
    secondCurr.attr('id',firstCurr.attr('id'));
    secondCurr.attr('name',firstCurr.attr('id'));
    firstCurr.attr('id',tmpID);
    firstCurr.attr('name',tmpID);
});
```

```css
#secondcurrency {
  float:right;
}
#firstcurrency {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="currency" name="form" onsubmit="return redirect(this)">

<div style="clear:both;text-align: center;">
  <select id="firstcurrency" class="selex" name="firstcurrency">
    <option value="usd">USD</option>
    <option value="btc">BTC</option>
  </select>

  <span style="margin: 0 auto;">=</span>

  <select id="secondcurrency" class="selex" name="secondcurrency">
    <option value="btc">RRR</option>
    <option value="xvg">XVG</option>
    <option value="xrp">XRP</option>
    <option value="ntx">NTX</option>
  </select>
  <p style="clear: both;"></p>
</div>

   <p><input class="button" type="submit" value="Redirect Me" ></p>

   <a id="invert" href="javascript:void(0)"><!--href="convertitore-home"<img src="/images/invert.png">-->Invert select</a>
```